# Having four different tables or having one table with one more field?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, optimization, database-design

I have a website with 4 translation (That is Arabic with 4 different Persian translation), and I had exported each of these translations to different tables.

#### **Which one of these ways are faster and better:**

> 1- Merging or Importing all of this translation (tables) to one table,
> and name it **nahj_all** and adding a flag field to table to clarify
> what translation is it *(for example flag with numbers 1, 2, 3 and
> 4)*.

OR

> 2- Importing each translation to different tables and get diffrent
> name to them according to translation name (or number), for example
> **nahj_feiz, nahj_jafari, nahj_dashti, nahj_shahidi**

I have these tables in **MySql** and I want to convert database to **sqlite**

**Which one is better for sqllite?**

**Which way is better for MySql?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach would be the more standard way to handle multiple languages.  Putting the information in one table has several advantages.  Notably, the same query can be written for *all* languages, the only change being a change to a parameter.

It is also easier to maintain a single table of translations, as opposed to multiple tables.  And, you can readily see what languages are available, and to add new languages as well.

Having a separate column for each language is generally a bad idea.  Although good for presentation purposes, it makes it hard to add a new language.

Comment: anyway which ways is better 1 or 2?

Comment: @LASH . . . The first way is better.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL its better to have 1 table with multiple columns:

Something like this :

```
Language key | feiz | jafari | dashti | shahidi
```

Then select translation from the language key with the user selected language.